# Aggregate function GROUP_CONCAT(expr) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I have problem in using the aggregate function **GROUP_CONCAT(expr)** in MySQL database:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

I have this table with this rows:

```
+------+------+
| NAME | AREA |
+------+------+
| and  | DM4  |
| ant  | DMS  |
| don  | DM7  |
| ett  | DM4  |
| fab  | DM4  |
| fra  | DMS  |
| gia  | DM7  |
| gug  | DM2  |
| raf  | DM   |
| rob  | DM2  |
| vin  | DM7  |
+------+------+
16 rows in set
```

And I tried aggregate query to obtain this output where the name **`raf`** should be present in all areas because your **`area`** is **`DM`**:

```
+------+------------------------------+
| AREA | group_emails                 |
+------+------------------------------+
| DM4  | and; ant; ett; fab; fra; raf |
| DM6  | and; ant; raf                |
| DM7  | and; don; gia; vin; raf      |
| DM2  | gug; rob; raf                |
| DMS  | ant; fra ; raf               |
+------+------------------------------+
```

I have tested this solution but the output is wrong.

This is beginning to make me believe my structure as a whole is not correct.

What am I missing ?

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem.

```
mysql> SELECT
    AREA,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT NAME
        ORDER BY
            NAME ASC SEPARATOR '; '
    ) AS group_emails
FROM
    `tbl_NAMES`
GROUP BY
        AREA
ORDER BY
    NAME ASC;
+------+-------------------------+
| AREA | group_emails            |
+------+-------------------------+
| DM4  | and; ant; ett; fab; fra |
| DM   | raf                     |
| DM6  | and; ant                |
| DM7  | and; don; gia; vin      |
| DM2  | gug; rob                |
| DMS  | ant; fra                |
+------+-------------------------+
6 rows in set
```

Comment: The output looks correct to me, why would you expect something different? If you group by area mysql will concatenate only the names which have the same area, in your expected result there are missing areas like `DM`.

Comment: I tried aggregate query to obtain the output where the name raf should be present in all areas because your area is DM; now the name raf is not present in all areas DM

Comment: apparently you want 'DM' to be some kind of wildcard for all DM? values. But it isn't. 'DM' != 'DM4' so when grouped it gets its own row.

Comment: Seems like a logically problem: You group by the area which does take every letter into account for grouping. But what you want is, that also areas beginning with DM should be taken into account. This is not covered by the group statement. So you have to choose another approach. Also in your should be output the DM result row is missing, so your should be list is wrong from the beginning. Rethink what you really need as output!

Comment: @antonia, can u make sqlfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to base your data on a union of a straight select with a join to itself using a `LIKE` comparison to collect all the names that "match":

```
SELECT
    AREA,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT NAME
        ORDER BY NAME
        SEPARATOR '; ') AS group_emails
FROM (
SELECT * FROM tbl_NAMES
UNION
SELECT t2.name, t1.AREA
FROM tbl_NAMES t1
LEFT JOIN tbl_NAMES t2
  ON t1.AREA like concat(t2.AREA, '%')
) x
GROUP BY AREA
ORDER BY group_emails
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab71e0/2)

Answer (score 0):

I would use this solution, that makes use of a JOIN:

```
SELECT areas.area, GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY name ASC SEPARATOR '; ') AS group_emails
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT area
   FROM tbl_names
   WHERE
     CHAR_LENGTH(area)>2) areas
  INNER JOIN tbl_names
  ON areas.area=tbl_names.area OR (CHAR_LENGTH(tbl_names.area)=2 AND areas.area LIKE CONCAT(tbl_names.area, '%'))
GROUP BY areas.area
ORDER BY areas.area
```

First subquery returns all AREAS that have length > 2 like DM4, DMS, DM7. I'm then joining this subquery back to your table on `areas.area=tbl_names.area` when the length is >2, or using a LIKE when the length of the area is 2.